# Нейросеть в Python

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Пытался написать нейросеть на питоне, которая сравнивает два слова и определяет похожи они или нет. Как я понял в первый (входной) массив нейронов требуется вложить числовые значения, но как это реализовать со строками?? Долго искал, нигде не нашел ответа

Comment: использовать `ord`: `print([ord(c) for c in 'hello'])`

Comment: Зависит от того, что вообще делает ваша нейросеть, какая у неё конфигурация. Если она по совпадению букв просто определяет, тогда да, можно просто каждый символ перевести в его цифровой код (главное чтобы одинаковые буквы одинаково переводились). Но есть же ещё эмбеддинги, которые работают вообще по-другому (Word2Vec) и там в числа бывает надо переводить уже целые слова, а не буквы.

Comment: Может хеш-слова и второй вход +1?!